# Building a linear constrait with 3 binary variables

Tags: constraints, julia, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to build a linear constraint that follows this logic

if either x1 = 1 or x2 =1 then y1 = 1

but if x1 = 0 and x2 = 0 then y1 = 0

if both x1 = 1 and x2= 1 then y1 = 1

Comment: Please add more detail showing what you have tried so far, why they did not work, and an example of your (failing) code. Currently, it is unclear how we can best help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Assumptions**:

- we are talking about integer-programming here
- `x1, x2 are binary-variables / integer-variables in [0, 1]`

The truth-table looks like:

```
x1    x2  ||  y1
----------------
0     0   ||   0   
0     1   ||   1
1     0   ||   1
1     1   ||   1
```

This is just:

```
y1 = x1 OR x2
```

This is trivially linearized (see [relevant answer on cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/12118/36164)):

```
y1 = binary-var / (could be integer-var too)

y1 <= x1 + x2
y1 >= x1
y1 >= x2
```